# Remove corner shadows on grouped UITableView with non-white background color

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I have found other questions about this but the solution is not working for me. I have a custom black color background and even with setting the separator style to single line I'm seeing the corner shadow. It's driving me nuts. I'm attaching a screenshot - you can even see it in the storyboard view. It seems people are saying the single line separator style is working for them with a white background. Is it my background color that's causing the problem here? What can I do to fix this?

I'm using iOS 6.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

self.**Your tableview**.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0; should round up the corner.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but still see them. Might be something else going on - in the code I was as a test even setting the separator style to none and was still seeing separators between the cells.